# I am creating a Pokemon card game using Javascript but am not sure if I am going about it the right way

Tags: javascript, war

player1 and player2 are both supposed to receive 3 random cards from the array. After the cards are drawn the cards should be discarded. I am not able to get 3 random cards into the players cards[] and also discard them. Is splice the best way to accomplish this?

```js
let pokemonCards = 
[
  { name: "Bulbasaur", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Caterpie", damage: 40 }, 
  { name: "Charmander", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Clefairy", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Jigglypuff", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Mankey", damage: 30 }, 
  { name: "Meowth", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Nidoran - female", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Nidoran - male", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Oddish", damage: 40 }, 
  { name: "Pidgey", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Pikachu", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Poliwag", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Psyduck", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Rattata", damage: 30 }, 
  { name: "Squirtle", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Vulpix", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Weedle",  damage: 40 }
]







// assign AI to player1 and player 2
// They should each draw 3 cards


let player1 = {
 cards: [], 
 
 }
 
let player2 = {
 cards: [],
 
 

 }



//functions
let randomCard = function(){
return randomCardValue = pokemonCards[Math.floor(Math.random()*pokemonCards.length)]
} 

let drawCards = function(){
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
 
  player1.cards.push(randomCard())
 pokemonCards.splice(randomCard(),1)
 
 
}
 }

drawCards()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I store the random selected card and remove the card from the deck using splice() and push the card into the player's hand. It should work.

```js
let pokemonCards = 
[
  { name: "Bulbasaur", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Caterpie", damage: 40 }, 
  { name: "Charmander", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Clefairy", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Jigglypuff", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Mankey", damage: 30 }, 
  { name: "Meowth", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Nidoran - female", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Nidoran - male", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Oddish", damage: 40 }, 
  { name: "Pidgey", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Pikachu", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Poliwag", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Psyduck", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Rattata", damage: 30 }, 
  { name: "Squirtle", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Vulpix", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Weedle",  damage: 40 }
]







// assign AI to player1 and player 2
// They should each draw 3 cards


let player1 = {
 cards: [], 
 
 }
 
let player2 = {
 cards: [],
 
 

 }



//functions
let randomCard = function(){
return randomCardValue = pokemonCards[Math.floor(Math.random()*pokemonCards.length)]
} 

let drawCards = function(){
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
 let selectedRandomCard = pokemonCards.splice(randomCard(),1)[0];
    console.log(selectedRandomCard);
 player1.cards.push(selectedRandomCard);
 
}
 }

drawCards()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest shuffling the deck. Then you don't need to worry about keeping track anything. You can just pop cards of like you would in a real deck.

Here's the standard Stack overflow answer about [shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), which I've used (in spirit) below. You can `pop()` your cards off in a loop if you want. But below uses [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which is a quick way to make an array without an explicit loop:

```js
// shuffles the deck in place
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length;
    while (0 !== --currentIndex) {
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [array[randomIndex],  array[currentIndex]];
    } 
    return array;
  }
  
  
let pokemonCards = 
[
  { name: "Bulbasaur", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Caterpie", damage: 40 }, 
  { name: "Charmander", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Clefairy", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Jigglypuff", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Mankey", damage: 30 }, 
  { name: "Meowth", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Nidoran - female", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Nidoran - male", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Oddish", damage: 40 }, 
  { name: "Pidgey", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Pikachu", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Poliwag", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Psyduck", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Rattata", damage: 30 }, 
  { name: "Squirtle", damage: 60 }, 
  { name: "Vulpix", damage: 50 }, 
  { name: "Weedle",  damage: 40 }
]

function deal(num_of_cards){
  // return an array of n cards
  return Array.from({length:num_of_cards}, () => pokemonCards.pop())
}

// randomize the deck order:
shuffle(pokemonCards)
console.log("deck length: ", pokemonCards.length)

// players should be in a datastructure of some sort
// not individual variables
let players = []
players.push({name: "player 1", cards: deal(3)})
players.push({name: "player 2", cards: deal(3)})

console.log(players[0])
console.log(players[1])
 
// double check deck length
console.log("deck length: ", pokemonCards.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, not everything is global, with something like a game, that matters... But that stuff aside, I'd say that using splice is probably the best approach, it's simple, easy to read, etc...

I've also taken the time to create a `config` object for you, I mean you may like it, dislike it, that's your shout, I just did it because I like to see it that way.

```js
const PokemonApp = function(myNameSpace) {
  const publicProps = {};
  const config = {
    cards: [
      { name: "Bulbasaur", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Caterpie", damage: 40 }, 
      { name: "Charmander", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Clefairy", damage: 50 }, 
      { name: "Jigglypuff", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Mankey", damage: 30 }, 
      { name: "Meowth", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Nidoran - female", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Nidoran - male", damage: 50 }, 
      { name: "Oddish", damage: 40 }, 
      { name: "Pidgey", damage: 50 }, 
      { name: "Pikachu", damage: 50 }, 
      { name: "Poliwag", damage: 50 }, 
      { name: "Psyduck", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Rattata", damage: 30 }, 
      { name: "Squirtle", damage: 60 }, 
      { name: "Vulpix", damage: 50 }, 
      { name: "Weedle",  damage: 40 }
    ],
    cardLimit: 3,
    players: [{ cards: [] }, { cards: [] }]
  };
  
  
  publicProps.getPlayer1 = () => { return {...config.players[0]} };
  publicProps.getPlayer2 = () => { return {...config.players[1]} };
  publicProps.getCards = () => { return [...config.cards] };
  
  
  const randomCard = () => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * config.cards.length);
    return {
      index: index, 
      card: config.cards[index]
    }
  };


  publicProps.drawCards = () => config.players.map(p => 
    Array.from({length: config.cardLimit}, () => { 
      const cardObject = randomCard();
      p.cards.push(cardObject.card);
      config.cards.splice(cardObject.index, 1);
  }));  
  
  
  myNameSpace.launch = () => {
    console.log('Launching App...');
    return publicProps;
  };
  
  
  return myNameSpace;
}({});


const app = PokemonApp.launch();
console.log(app.getCards()); // before.
app.drawCards();
console.log(app.getCards()); // after.
console.log(app.getPlayer1());
console.log(app.getPlayer2());
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues:

1. You are calling `splice()` wrong (the first argument needs to be the index you'll start splicing and the second should be the delete count: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice ) Thus, you need to know the index of the card you are randomly choosing. You can modify your `randomCards()` function to achieve that.
2. You are calling `randomCards` twice in the `drawCards` function, both of which returns a different result. For consistency call it once in every loop, assign the result to a variable and use that variable when pushing and splicing.

I believe the following snippet does what you want your code to do:

```
//functions
let randomCard = function() {
    let randomCardIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemonCards.length)
    let randomCardValue = pokemonCards[randomCardIndex]
    return [randomCardIndex, randomCardValue]
} 

let drawCards = function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        let card = randomCard();

        player1.cards.push(card[1])
        pokemonCards.splice(card[0], 1)
    }
}
```